# Mangeto working under an IP address and not a domain

Tags: magento

We are rebuilding our Magento website and got a new server. We are currently installing Magento under an IP : http://138.201.29.41/
That worked fine. But when importing or adding products the images are not showing up and i don't understand why: http://prntscr.com/as2nup

Could this be due to using an IP rather then a domain?

Comment: It looks like a web server related problem. Probably because of your .htaccess settings under media directory. I see that skin directory works fine. Check your apache error log, you may find a clue.

Comment: Fixed. It was due to using an IP rather then domain.

Answer (score 0):

Correct that. In my situation it was a .htaccess file in the media folder. Removed that and it was all fixed.